# Как сделать сортировку?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, sql

Здравствуйте, помогите мне с таким вопросом. Как сделать сортировку в Delphi7 через SQL запрос. У меня в один DBGrid собираются данные с двух таблиц, с одним полем "model".
Как сделать сортировку в этом DBGride? Вот запрос, который собирает две таблицы:

```
SELECT *
FROM "director_2.db"  director_2
WHERE   (model = :model )
UNION
SELECT *
FROM "buh_2.db"  buh_2
WHERE   (model = :model )
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
(SELECT *
FROM "director_2.db"  director_2
WHERE   (model = :model )
UNION
SELECT *
FROM "buh_2.db"  buh_2
WHERE   (model = :model )
) order by 'некое поле' desc
```

Попробуйте так

Comment: если так, он на 'некое поле'ругается

Comment: Ну ошибку напишите полностью.

Comment: Если UNION
Вместо 'некое поле' впешите не название колонки в таблице базы без кавычек а номер. 

 Например order by 1 desc

Comment: Да, только ковычки измените, вместо ' поставьте `


SELECT *
(SELECT *
FROM "director_2.db"  director_2
WHERE   (model = :model )
UNION
SELECT *
FROM "buh_2.db"  buh_2
WHERE   (model = :model )
) order by `поле` desc

Comment: > Не обезательно для некоторыз СУБД достаточно чтобы типы совпадали 

Это в каких базах, можно пример такого запроса.

Comment: например 
SELECT F1,F2
FROM "director_2.db"  director_2
WHERE   (model = :model )
UNION
SELECT F3 as F1,F4 as F2
FROM "buh_2.db"  buh_2
WHERE   (model = :model )

Answer (score 0):

Название полей в 2 таблицах должны быть одинаковыми, должны совпадать

Comment: Необезательно, для некоторых СУБД достаточно, чтобы типы совпадали.